# Cannot access websites by URL (squid transparent)

Tags: squid

I set up transparent proxy in squid. 
I can access web sites by their IP addresses. 
But I cannot access web sites by their URLs.

This is my UFW.log

```
Mar  7 09:28:22 proxy kernel: [75293.384239] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens18 OUT=ens18 MAC=e6:b5:75:1f:8d:61:5c:9a:d8:e6:4a:14:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.11 DST=8.8.4.4 LEN=56 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=1935 PROTO=UDP SPT=54333 DPT=53 LEN=36.
```

My proxy's ip address is 192.168.1.101 
Client's ip address is 192.168.1.11

UFW redirects all http (80/tcp) traffic to port 3128.

What may be the problem?

Comment: The log line shows blocked outgoing DNS requests.

Comment: How can I redirect all traffic to port 3128?

Comment: That's not what you want, not all traffic can be proxied by squid. You did not explain what is your goal, what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to use transparent proxy. When I surf the Internet, I want to go through Squid proxy. As a gateway I set my Proxy's IP address.

Comment: Just to clarify what we are talking about - transparent means you do not need any client modification, it's usually done somewhere on the network (LAN gateway for example, of course can be done also on single client device via local fw); on the other hand clients' web tools can be configured to use whatever proxy. For transparent proxy you would need to allow outgoing DNS requests from clients, modify fw to redirect HTTP to transparent proxy. For HTTPS it's even more problematic, you would need to do TLS interception on Squid (for example). BTW redirecting HTTP only make no much sense in 2021.

Comment: I redirected all my HTTP traffic to transparent proxy. The problem is that I cant open web sites by their URL names, I can open them only by their IP addresses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120532/discussion-between-jiri-b-and-it-dev).

Comment: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128